# Insert list in RichEditBox for Windows store application

Tags: windows, list, windows-runtime, uwp, richeditbox

I develop text editor for the Windows store application (WinRT) based on RichEditBox control. 
RichEditBox use ITextParagraphFormat for paragraph operation and ListAlignment, ListLevelIndex and other properties for bulleted and numbered lists.
I not found any samples to insert bulleted or numbered lists to RichEditBox. 
How I can to add lists to RichEditBox using ITextParagraphFormat?

Comment: Have you resolved it?

Comment: Yes. Thank's. I add `paragraphFormatting1.ListStart = 1;` for numbered list and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the [ITextParagraphFormat.ListType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextparagraphformat.listtype.aspx) property for the ITextParagraphFormat. For bullet, set the ListType property to `MarkerType.Bullet`, for number, set the ListType to `MarkerType.Arabic`. More types please reference the [MarkerType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.markertype.aspx) enumeration to choose other list types you want.

Here is a sample about adding the bullet and number to the selected paragraph list in the RichEditBox you can test.

XAML Code

```
 <RichEditBox x:Name="Richbox"  Height="400" Margin="40" >          
 </RichEditBox>    
 <Button x:Name="BtnSetbullet" Content="set bullet  to richeditbox" Click="BtnSetbullet_Click"></Button>
 <Button x:Name="BtnSetNumber" Content="set number  to richeditbox" Click="BtnSetNumber_Click"></Button>
```

Code behind

```
 private void BtnSetbullet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {         
     Windows.UI.Text.ITextSelection selectedText = Richbox.Document.Selection;
     ITextParagraphFormat paragraphFormatting = selectedText.ParagraphFormat;

     paragraphFormatting.ListType = MarkerType.Bullet;          
     selectedText.ParagraphFormat = paragraphFormatting;

 } 
 private void BtnSetNumber_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Windows.UI.Text.ITextSelection selectedText = Richbox.Document.Selection;
     ITextParagraphFormat paragraphFormatting = selectedText.ParagraphFormat;      
     paragraphFormatting.ListType = MarkerType.Arabic; 
     selectedText.ParagraphFormat = paragraphFormatting;           
 }
```