# How to create a RichEditBox with support for Inking Like OneNote?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I want to create a RichEditBox with support for Inking Like OneNote. It should have features from both, like Text Formating and Ink editing.

Note: I have requested [UWPCommunityToolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues/1081) to create a new control for this. If you would like to have that, please Upvote it in [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/18869671-create-a-custom-richeditbox-with-all-the-basic-fea)

Comment: I received a notification about this on GitHub. I was actually working on something like this a few months back but had to shelve the project due to Time constraints. If the guys from UWPCommunityToolkit can put together something like this, It would be Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

> It should have features from both, like Text Formating and Ink editing

[`RichEditBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox) have many relative APIs to execute the basic features as what you mentioned. For example, you can change the text formatting by [`ITextCharacterFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextcharacterformat). The [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlUIBasics/cs/AppUIBasics/ControlPages/RichEditBoxPage.xaml.cs) provide samples about changing the text bold, italic, color you can reference. You can bullet and numbering by setting the [`ITextParagraphFormat.ListType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextparagraphformat.listtype.aspx) property for the [`ITextParagraphFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Text.ITextParagraphFormat#Windows_UI_Text_ITextParagraphFormat_ListType). [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318252/insert-list-in-richeditbox-for-windows-store-application) provide sample for bullet and numbering for [`RichEditBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox).

For inking, you may use the [`InkCanvas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.inkcanvas) with [`InkToolbar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.inktoolbar). Inking can be edit, copy, delete and so on. Details please reference the [SimpleInk](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleInk) official sample.

So before a powerful, combined control appeared, try the above controls and their APIs to implement your requirements.

Comment: But how OneNote was implemented?

Comment: @VijayNirmal, onenote is not open source but seems like they didn't use a `RichEditBox`. You may try to custom your control.